# What happened to "Apply" and "Apply and Close" for styles in Delphi 10.1 Berlin?

Tags: delphi, ide, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

In Delphi 10 Seattle, when you're editing a style, there are 3 buttons on the top-right of the editor window's toolbar:

- Apply
- Apply and Close
- Cancel

[image: Delphi 10 Seattle Style Editor Toolbar]

However, now that I'm using Delphi 10.1 Berlin, these buttons are no longer there:

[image: Delphi 10.1 Berlin Style Editor Toolbar]

I relied on these buttons to actually apply the styles. Since Embarcadero has removed these buttons, I now am at the mercy of just closing that tab:

[image: Delphi 10.1 Berlin Style Editor Close]

As you can see, this becomes annoying. I also have to count on seeing the prompt to apply the styles, so I have no sure way to apply the styles. My form(s) don't even update with the new style until I explicitly "apply" it. But, since these buttons are gone, I now am forced to close the tab in order to apply the styles. Even if I save all files, it doesn't seem to apply.

How can I forcefully apply my styles while I'm editing, without closing the style editor tab? Am I missing something? I've checked all the documentation and what's new information on these changes...

Comment: Seems that button is missing in Berlin. It is present again in Tokyo, though (last button to the right).

Comment: If you click on the X button, you get a popup window asking whether you want the changes to be applied

Comment: @John Yes, I know this, I explain it in my question. My point is that I shouldn't have to close it to apply my changes. I like to be able to apply, look at my changes, then go back and adjust it more as needed. Every time I close it, I lose my place. Not to mention in the first place, "Edit [...] Style..." no longer takes me to the specific style but lists all of them (but that's another issue).

Answer (score 0):

It would appear these buttons have been completely removed in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, and you're forced to close the style editor in order to apply them. However, in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo, these buttons are back.

So the only thing you can do is close that tab every time you want to apply your styles, until you move up to Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.